# Error correcting permutation code

Tags: coding-theory, permutations, encoding-scheme, error-correcting-codes

Let's say you have $n$ symbols. You can encode a $\log_2(n!)$-bit message by permutating the symbols. I will call this a permutation code (if you have seen this concept before, I would love to see a reference).

Let's say we are encoding a message with $k<\log_2(n!)$ bits. It is possible to add error correction. One way is to simply add any old error correction scheme to the string before applying the permutation code. I'm wondering if there is a way that is optimal for permutation codes.

In particular, is there some way of doing a permutation coding that is resistant to transpositions (in terms of error detection and correction)?  I want something that will tolerate up to $t$ transpositions of *adjacent* symbols.

Comment: Try $k \le \log_2 (n/2)!$ by repeating twice every symbols in $n/2$ symbols.

Comment: Have a look at this paper as it addresses your error model: http://www.paradise.caltech.edu/papers/etr122.pdf

Comment: This is the journal version:  http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7435295/

Answer (score 2):

The first reference seems to be [Rank permutation group codes based on Kendall's correlation statistic](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1054291/) by Chadwick and Kurz; your notion of distance is known as [Kendall's tau distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance). A more modern reference is [Codes in Permutations and Error Correction for
Rank Modulation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.4094.pdf) by Alexander Barg and Arya Mazumdar